# Grep : get all file that doesn't have a line that matches

Tags: file, grep

I have a lots of files with multiple lines, and in most case, one of the lines contain a certain pattern. I would like to list every file that does not have a line with this pattern.

Comment: why did I get -1 for this one ?!

Comment: My guess is that someone thought that info was readily available in the manual.

Comment: If you've found an answer, don't edit your question with it, *post* the answer instead. Nowadays you can even accept your own answers.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the "-L" option in order to have file WITHOUT the pattern. Per the man page:

> -L, --files-without-match
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed. The scanning will stop on the first match.

Answer (score 6):

Grep returns 0/1 to indicate if there was a match, so you can do something like this:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    if ! grep -q "some expression" $f; then
        echo $f
    fi
done
```

**EDIT**: You can also use the -L option:

grep -L "some expression" *

Comment: no need for loop just have to use "-L" option of grep.

Answer (score 0):

try "count" and filter where equals ":0":

```
grep -c [pattern] * | grep ':0$'
```

(if you use TurboGREP *cough*, you won't have a -L switch ;))

(EDIT: added '$' to end of regex in case there are files with ":0" in the name)

Comment: TurboGREP does seem to have -l and -v, so you could just use `grep -lv 'expr' *`.

Comment: if turbogrep works like gnu grep, -lv does not do what you want.  it shows you all files with any line that doesn't match the expression.